# Image Display Using p:graphicImage. Pictures appear like negatives

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces p:graphicImage to display the image of every logged in users. Everything is working near fine except that my photos appear like negatives. What could I be doing wrong. Here is my code :

```
<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
   <span>
     <p:graphicImage value="#{currentUser.image}" class="img-thumbnail pull-right"
        height="80px;" width="80px;" >
       <f:param name="id" value="#{request.remoteUser}" />
     </p:graphicImage>
   </span>

.....

And here is the JSF Managed Bean


@Named(value = "currentUser")
@ApplicationScoped
public class CurrentUser implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private VempDetailsFacade vempDetailsFacade;
    private VempDetails details;

    public StreamedContent getImage() throws IOException {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
            // So, we're rendering the HTML. Return a stub StreamedContent so that it will generate right URL.
            return new DefaultStreamedContent();
        } else {
            // So, browser is requesting the image. Return a real StreamedContent with the image bytes.
            String imageId = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id");
            details = vempDetailsFacade.find(imageId);
            if (details != null) {
                try {
                    return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(details.getEmpImage()));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("No Image Retrieved : "+e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return null;

        }
    }

    public VempDetails getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(VempDetails details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        details = vempDetailsFacade.
                find(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser());
    }

}
```

What is it I could be doing wrong. The same pictures displayed in a normal swing application display without any problem

Update On Code

@BalusC
Here is the quick test code that displays the image on swing.

```
public DisplayImage() {
        super("Image Display");
        setSize(600, 600);
        connection = getConnection();
        try { 
            statement = connection
                    .prepareStatement("SELECT empImage FROM v_empDetails WHERE empCode=?");
            statement.setString(1, "009");
            result = statement.executeQuery();

            byte[] image = null;
            //just a result anyway
            while (result.next()) {
                image = result.getBytes(1);         
            }
            Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(image);
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
            JLabel lPhoto = new JLabel();
            lPhoto.setIcon(icon);
            add(lPhoto);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        Connection connection = null;
........
```

Could it be that the  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(image); line is doing the re-invert. The images were populated using a different application and this is more of an update to have it as a web-based application.

Thanks for your advice in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSF/PrimeFaces is just the presenter and doesn't invert the images at all. Otherwise anyone else in the world using JSF/PrimeFaces would have faced the same problem. Your problem lies deeper. It's more likely that the images are already stored as negatives in DB and that your existing Swing/Java2D code is written in such way that it re-inverts the images before displaying, perhaps during a badly written resizing/cropping process.

So, to fix the problem, refocus on the code responsible for storing those images in the DB (and don't forget to fix the Swing/Java2D code to not re-invert those anymore).

Comment: thanks bro for the pointer, recreated the photo by saving the ones that had been re-inverted locally, clearing the one stored in the database and re-uploading the images. The display is now working like a charm....;-)